# ImportError: cannot import name '_plain_int' from 'werkzeug._internal'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, werkzeug

Got an error while deploying docker flaskapp image as aws ecs service
error:
ImportError: cannot import name '_plain_int' from 'werkzeug._internal' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/werkzeug/_internal.py)

same docker runs perfectly on my local system and even on aws which i deployed 3 weeks ago now.
Werkzeug==2.2.3

I did not made any changes in requirements of images but still it fails to run.
It is expected to run properly

Comment: fixed by upgrading the version of Werkzeug