# ImportError while running tensorboard command: cannot import name '_plain_int' from 'werkzeug._internal'

Tags: tensorboard, werkzeug

While running tensorboard command, I have got the following import error: ImportError: cannot import name '_plain_int' from 'werkzeug._internal'. I have upgraded the Werkzeug to the last version released but still have the error. Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your version of `werkzeug` may not be the good one.
I fixed this issue by installing the package using the following command:

`conda install -c conda-forge werkzeug`

It installed the version 2.3.7 that works for me.

See also: [ImportError: cannot import name '_plain_int' from 'werkzeug._internal'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76710888/importerror-cannot-import-name-plain-int-from-werkzeug-internal)
for a similar question. The author solved the issue by updating the package.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when running tensorboard, and the solution is:

```
conda install werkzeug
```

When it is updated, it is ok to run tensorboard again.
[Record of problem solving process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Yip.jpg)